# Adding a new virtual device support in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to add a new virtual device support in virtualbox. I found a sample code under the vbox source /src/VBox/Devices/Samples.How can i add this sample device in to a guest .

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to hunt this down myself. I found the answer in VMM/VMMR3/PDMDevice.cpp in the virtual box source tree.

Assuming 4.2.8:
Use

```
VirtualBoxManage setextradata  VBoxInternal/PDM/Devices/[[ID]]/Path  path/to/.dll/or/.so
```

[[ID]] is an identifier that you chose to identify your module.